# Sequence of plotting in python

Tags: python, plot

I have plotted a figure as show below,
[image]

the way I ploted it is

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.scatter(x, y, c='r')               <- scatter

plt.hist(x, bins = 100, normed=True)   <- histogram
plt.show()
```

I would like to show the all red points in scatterplot first and not be covered by the bins of histogram (be the upper layer). How can I do it ? thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for the zorder keyword argument

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.scatter(x, y, c='r', zorder=1)

plt.hist(x, bins = 100, normed=True, zorder=0)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an option to the `scatter` and `hist` that specifies the plot order. it is called `zorder` and can be used like this:

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.scatter(x, y, c='r', zorder=2)               <- scatter

plt.hist(x, bins = 100, normed=True, zorder=1)   <- histogram
plt.show()
```

Higher number in the option puts the plot on a higher layer.
Read more about it here: [zorder demo](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html)